# How to transfer a save in candy box 1 from the iPad to the PC?

Tags: candy-box

I took some advice from someone and I can't figure out how to transfer a save from my iPad to my PC to beat the hell level.

Answer (score 1):

From your ipad, on the main page, click the save button and take note of the given code.

Then browse to: http://candies.aniwey.net/index.php?pass=[your_code] -- where you replace the the insides of the brackets with the code you received.

e.g. http://candies.aniwey.net/index.php?pass=12345